# Select statement with where condition in oracle by python a space and alphabetical parameter not working

Tags: python, oracle

currently data in table of this service if i am using year and month then query give proper output but if i am using all three variable in same case query give 0 output

```
**mis_year="2016"
mis_month="2"
name="HB (HIB)"
Q2 = myC1.execute('select * from r13 where MIS_SERVICE= :name and MIS_SERVICE_YEAR= :mis_year and MIS_SERVICE_MONTH= :mis_month',name=name,mis_year=mis_year,mis_month=mis_month)**
```

Comment: Please post your table `DDL`. Aren't you by any chance using the `CHAR` data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Q2 = myC1.execute('select * from r13 where trim(MIS_SERVICE)=:name and MIS_SERVICE_YEAR= :mis_year and MIS_SERVICE_MONTH= :mis_month',name=name,mis_year=mis_year,mis_month=mis_month)
```

Comment: its make error ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Comment: @RahulHarode Also try without quotes but keep the trim .... I've edited the answer.